# BUild artifacts names in jenkins/maven build

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, build

New in Jenkins.

Currently we have the manual build process using maven and Subversion as SCM:

1. in the local working copy folder, the POM file has 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT, issue 
   mvn release:clean release:prepare -P all-modules

   this creates a tag https://avn/path/to/tag/xxx-1.1.1, while my local working copy is still in 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
2. issue
   svn switch https://avn/path/to/tag/xxx-1.1.1

   this will update the POM's in my local working copy back to 1.1.1
3. issue
   mvn clean install -Dbuild.env=pt -DskipTests=true -P all-modules

   this will create EAR file with build number 1.1.1 in the name as we expected

now I am automating the process with JENKINS, I put the command #1 and #3 into the Goals and options:
release:clean release:prepare -P all-modules clean install -Dbuild.env=pt -DskipTests=true -P all-modules

the process runs with no problem, but the EAR files have always -SNAPSHOT in the name, and the build number is 1.1.2-SNAPSHOT, not 1.1.1.

I know it is because the the time of "install", the POM's have 1.1.2-NAPSHOT as version/parent version.

What is the way I can get around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to workaround with mix of batch command and perl.

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('perl -ne "print join('.',$2, $3, $4-1) if (/\((\d+).(\d+).(\d+))/) && ($. <= 20)" pom.xml') do @set ver=%%a

svn switch https://svn/path/to/myproject/tags/myproject-%ver%`